# "Stable" distributions with integer support?

Tags: random-variable, stable-distribution

My understanding of stable distributions is that in order for a distribution to be stable, linear combinations of independent random variables from a given distribution (for example, a Gaussian) must also follow that distribution.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution

Are there any stable distributions with support on the integers (or natural numbers)? If not, is there a related notion of a "stability" for distributions with these supports?

For example, the sum of independent Poisson random variables is itself a Poisson RV, but this is not the case for arbitrary linear combinations of Poisson RVs, so it is not stable. I am interested in the theory regarding these sorts of distributions, but I'm not sure about the language to use in my searches.

Comment: **Edit:** 

It would seem this is called a Discrete-stable distribution 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-stable_distribution